# What is this pointer increment operation achieving here

Tags: c++

I'm looking at some C++ code that looks like the following:

```
char* foo = strchr(sStr, '\t');
if (foo)
{
  *foo++ = '\0';
  /* more code */
}
```

I'm assuming more context isn't needed -- I understand the first line is initializing a pointer to the first occurrence in `sStr`. I'm not entirely sure what `*foo++ = '\0';` is doing, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
*foo++ = '\0';
```

sets the character that `foo` points to to the value `'\0'` (the null character), and then moves the pointer so that it points to the next character. It is equivalent to:

```
*foo = '\0';
foo = foo + 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

That is the standard incantation for "access an array element and advance to the next one". It's directly analogous to doing something like `foo[i++]` for iterating through an array.

The expression itself parses as

```
*(foo++) = '\0';
```

`foo++` means "increment foo, but use its current value in this expression". Thus, this expression assigns `'\0'` to the `char` object that `foo` is *currently* pointing to, and advances `foo` to point to the next element.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are correct: `foo` is pointing to a tab in `sStr`, so the line `*foo++ = '\0';` replaces the tab with a NUL and advances `foo` to point to the next character.

The reason you might do this is to parse a line of text into tab-separated fields.  I would be surprised if the `/* more code */` wasn't doing that (*i.e.*, recording pointers to the beginnings of fields, and separating them by replacing the tabs with NULs.)